# flutter ontap error ontap stopped working

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

i'm getting null error in flutter button stopped working after added `if` statement inside the ontap here is my flutter code

```
import 'package:efood_multivendor/controller/product_controller.dart';
import 'package:efood_multivendor/util/dimensions.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:get/get_instance/src/extension_instance.dart';
import 'package:get/get_utils/src/extensions/internacionalization.dart';

import 'custom_snackbar.dart';

class QuantityButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isIncrement;
  final Function onTap;
  final int quantity;
  final int stock;
  QuantityButton(
      {@required this.isIncrement,
      @required this.onTap,
      @required this.quantity,
      @required this.stock});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
       onTap : onTap({
        if (!isIncrement && quantity > 1) {
          Get.find<ProductController>().setQuantity(false),
        } else if (isIncrement) {
          if (quantity < stock) {
            Get.find<ProductController>().setQuantity(true),
          } else {
            showCustomSnackBar('out_of_stock'.tr),
          }
        }
      }),
      child: Container(
        height: 22,
        width: 22,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: Border.all(
              width: 1,
              color: isIncrement
                  ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                  : Theme.of(context).disabledColor),
          color: isIncrement
              ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
              : Theme.of(context).disabledColor.withOpacity(0.2),
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Icon(
          isIncrement ? Icons.add : Icons.remove,
          size: 15,
          color: isIncrement
              ? Theme.of(context).cardColor
              : Theme.of(context).disabledColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

if i try removing if statement and add `onTap:onTap` it is working
i'm getting `Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: '<Unexpected Null Value>'`  error still button not working

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a function to get a clear code.

replace **,** with **;** to end your command

```dart
InkWell(
       onTap : (){
        if (!isIncrement && quantity > 1) {
          Get.find<ProductController>().setQuantity(false);
        } else if (isIncrement) {
          if (quantity < stock) {
            Get.find<ProductController>().setQuantity(true);
          } else {
            showCustomSnackBar('out_of_stock'.tr);
          }
}
```

Good luck with it.

Comment: i'm getting ```Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: '<Unexpected Null Value>'
``` error still button not working

Comment: if i try removing ```if``` statement and add ```onTap:onTap```it is working